# How To include a Command askinge "do you want to overwrite" a file in a script

Tags: batch-file

Whanever I am moving a file one to other location by a script the file automaticly overwrite if same name of file already there.
what command should I include in my script so that it would ask before overwrite the same file?

```
@echo off
setlocal
call "H:\data\datefolder"
set TargetFolder=H:\data\%DateFolder%\final reports

call :moveAndRename "H:\data\final\XYZfolder" "%TargetFolder%\Xyz.csv"
call :moveAndRename "H:\data\final\XYZfolder2" "%TargetFolder%\Xyz2.csv"


:: Done
goto :eof



:moveAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2


:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: move and rename it to the target
copy "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"

Pause

:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MOVE /-Y file1.txt file2.txt
```

´MOVE´ now ask for every overwriting. Look at `move /?` at the command prompt.

Comment: Hi Endoro thx for help, I have updated my codng into the Question. Can you please let me know where I can include that command?